# Convert record based (multiline) text to csv with awk

Tags: awk

My input file looks like this:

```
Session: 324098324
Object: dd02:/24
Time: Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST
Status: Error
ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991

Session: 324321
Object: ad02:/24
Time: Sun 13 May 2018 12:00:43 PM CEST
Status: Ok
ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/21857092

Session: 132452
Object: xd01:/24
Time: Sun 08 Jul 2018 12:16:56 PM CEST
Status: Error
ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/21695878
```

Output should be: [WRONG]

```
Session: 324098324, Object: ad02:/24, Time: Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Status: Error, ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
Session: 324098324, Object: ad02:/24, Time: Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Status: Error, ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
Session: 324098324, Object: ad02:/24, Time: Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Status: Error, ID: 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
```

EDIT: I did a big failure with the output format, the above one is not usable as a CSV, i need a format like:

```
Session, Object, Time, Status, ID
324098324, ad02:/24, Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Error, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
324098324, ad02:/24, Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Error, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
324098324, ad02:/24, Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:40:41 AM CEST, Error, 5F2B0121-4F2B-481D-B79F-2DC827B85093/16123991
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print}' input
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i played around with `awk '{ORS=" ";}; !NF{ORS="\n"};1' input` but had no idea how to insert the "," as a seperator, i should look more into gsub, thanks again.

Comment: @T-One if you want to use field / record separators only, try `awk -vRS= 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; OFS=", "} {$1=$1} 1'`

Comment: Thanks for the command. I cannot figure out why this is not changing also the last of the `\n` to `,`.

Answer (score 1):

`paste` available? Try

```
paste -s -d"\t\t\t\t\t\n" file
```

Comment: CSV = Comma Separate Values Your answer currently provides TSV (Tab Seperate Values) output. This is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -A4  "Session " myfile | paste -s -d '    \n'`

`grep` finds word session and prints 4 lines after success.

`paste` converts them to single line.

You can easily set output delimiter by `paste -s -d '||||\n' OR paste -s -d ',,,,\n'`